# cURL retrieve json data and store in mysql database from url

Tags: mysql, sql, json, database, curl

i'm facing problems into **cURL**. here i can get the json data from another source code and also i got some ideas. but really i can't save the json data into my own server in sql database. i wanna to retrieve the data from

> url: https://jamuna.tv/wp-json/wp/v2/posts

and wanna to save into my server (mysql).

here is the $url json data i wanna to save in mysql server:

```
id
date
link
title
content
author
categories
wp:attachment
```

and i want to save them into mysql database. my table name is "news" and i want to save them into my table columns.

```
id [id]
title [title]
description [content]
date [date]
category [categories]
thumbnail [wp:attachment]
admin [author]
```

here i'm mark the json from url and replaced into my sql columns name. if anyone can give me the instructions about how i can fetch the data from user and save into mysql.

thanks advance.

Comment: no one here to help me?

Comment: your request is not clear! What is your problem exactly?

Comment: i want to fetch wp-json data into mysql database from another website. here is the example website: https://jamuna.tv/wp-json/wp/v2/posts

Comment: you can save it as string in DB! if you need to extract filed and save each property in a single column, what is your preferred language to do that? PHP? JAVA?

Comment: i want to do that using php. can you help me with an example? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an implementation of your desired with PHP. You must check if values are valid or not or if the array members exist or not. This is just a primitive implementation of your example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php

// db connection
$options = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
);

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;', 'user', 'pass', $options);

// download json from url
$json = file_get_contents('https://jamuna.tv/wp-json/wp/v2/posts');

echo '<br/>';

$sql = "INSERT INTO `mytable` (`id`,`title`,`description`,`date`,`category`,`thumbnail`,`admin`)
                      VALUES (:id, :title, :content , :date, :categories, :attachment, :author)";
$stm = $db->prepare($sql);

// parse JSON
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
$i = 0;

foreach ($arr as $record) {

    echo "==================Insert record " . $i ++ . "<br>";

    $data = array(
        ':id' => $record['id'],
        ':title' => $record['title']['rendered'],
        ':content' => $record['content']['rendered'],
        ':date' => $record['date'],
        ':categories' => $record['categories'][0],
        ':attachment' => $record['_links']['wp:attachment'][0]['href'],
        ':author' => $record['author']
    );

    var_dump($data);
    // inserting a record
    $stm->execute($data);
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi dear, it's working but i'm facing a problem. i'm saved this into stack.php file. and while i'm opening the stack.php file it showing the data like this "array(7) { [":id"]=> int(168534) [":title"]=> string(99) "রেস্টুরেন্টের মেঝেতে মাছেদের জলকেলি" [":content"]=> string(2748) ""... and with that, it's showing some youtube videos from jamuna.tv website.

Comment: You must comment out `var_dump` and `echo` lines! It was for seeing output work properly. If it works you can accept Answer!

Comment: ok... thanks for your answer.! is this possible to refresh this page itself in 60s? no need human to refresh this, it will automatically do that.

Comment: Yes! It is possible in PHP.

Comment: thanks for your kind of information. but here i'm facing more one issue. the wp:attachment retrieve a json link for media. it's not a image file to show in extension jpg or png. "https://jamuna.tv/wp-jso…p/v2/media?parent=168589" mysql database saving that. but i need jpg and png format. can i extract this above link like that: "https://jamuna.tv/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/aada585a-7.jpg"? if possible, then how? it's another json link. but we are extracting post data. it's a big problem for me.

Comment: I showed you how to extract it in the response. No need to say thanks in stackoverflow, just upvote or accept answer.